# Can Asp.net MVC3 run on WinXP IIS 5.1?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, iis

I am reading an MVC3 book, it said that Windows IIS 6 recommanded.

Can I run my MVC3 project on IIS5.1 on WinXP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, we do some MVC3 development on Windows XP with IIS 5.1 and everything works fine, debugging, running etc, all works.